# MySQL return only the first 5 datasets

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Is it possible to return only a specific number of datasets in mysqli?

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("server", "root", "passwd", "database");
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM xy WHERE num = '315' DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    /*return here only 5 datasets*/
}
```

Sorry I'm new at PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats very easy:

In your SQL-Query you can choose how much datasets you want to have with:

```
LIMIT 0, 5
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM xy WHERE num = '135' DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

This returns the frist 5 given sets

Comment: if you want to have dataset 5 to 10 `LIMIT 5, 10` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql limit

> LIMIT clause that is used to specify the number of records to return

```
SELECT * FROM xy WHERE num = '135' ORDER BY column_name DESC  LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query says "return only 5 records, start on record 0 (OFFSET -1)"

```
SELECT * FROM xy WHERE num = '135' ORDER BY column_name DESC  LIMIT 5 OFFSET -1
```